# Type of non-terminating function in Erlang

Tags: types, erlang, dialyzer

I'm learning Erlang and trying to use Dialyzer to get maximum type-safety when it's possible. There's a thing that I don't understand: what is the type of *non-terminating* function and how to denote it in `-spec`. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A function that loops forever and never terminates has the return type `no_return()`.  (That return type is also used for functions that always throw exceptions, e.g. a custom error function.  If you don't specify that return type, Dialyzer will tell you that the function "has no local return".)

This is mentioned in the [Types and Function Specifications](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html) chapter of the Erlang Reference Manual:

> Some functions in Erlang are not meant to return; either because they define servers or because they are used to throw exceptions, as in the following function:
>
> ```
> my_error(Err) -> erlang:throw({error, Err}).
> ```
>
> For such functions, it is recommended to use the special `no_return()` type for their "return", through a contract of the following form:
>
> ```
> -spec my_error(term()) -> no_return().
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think that this can be also applied to non-terminating functions!

Comment: This blog post describes the (unintentional) difference between `no_return()` and `none()` types in Dialyzer: http://joedevivo.com/2015/06/14/no-local-return.html

Answer (score 0):

The following examples are in Elixir, but I believe they make the use of `no_return` and `none` in typespecs clear for Erlangers too:

```
 defmodule TypeSpecExamples do
   @moduledoc """
   Examples of typespecs using no_return and none.
   """

   @spec forever :: no_return
   def forever do
     forever()
   end

   @spec only_for_side_effects :: no_return
   def only_for_side_effects do
     IO.puts "only_for_side_effects"
     :useless_return_value # delete this line to return the value of the previous line
   end

   @spec print_dont_care :: no_return
   def print_dont_care do
     IO.puts("""
       A no_return function that does not loop always returns a value, \
       which can be anything, such as the atom #{only_for_side_effects()}
       """)
   end

   @spec always_crash :: none
   def always_crash do
     raise "boom!"
   end

   @spec value_or_crash(boolean) :: number | none
   def value_or_crash(b) do
     if b do
       1
     else
       raise "boom!"
     end
   end

 end
```