# Suspend a Erlang process by using receive after infinity timeout

Tags: process, erlang, dialyzer

I'm new to Erlang and I want to suspend in a function. I use receive with infinity timeout, my function looks like:

```
suspend() ->
  receive
  after
     infinity->ok
  end.
```

When I ran dialyzer tool, it return "Function has no local return". Should I replace this function with timer:sleep(infinity). For suspend, which one is better? Thank you so much.

Comment: Use the advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37185394/409228) to eliminate the dialyzer warning: add `-spec suspend() -> no_return().` on the line before the function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `timer:sleep/1` is defined as:

```
sleep(T) ->
    receive
    after T -> ok
    end.
```

which is essentially the same as your `suspend/0` function, so either approach would work. I'd advise using `timer:sleep/1`, though, as it's already defined for you, and anyone reading it will instantly know what it is and what it does.